# Angular 2 urlsearchparams number format issues

Tags: angular

I am writing a function for inserting a data using urlsearchparams

```
data_info = new URLSearchParams();
data_info.append('email', data.email);
data_info.append('password', data.password);
data_info.append('number',data.number)
```

Actually error occurs when i set the number i think urlsearchparams only accepts string so is there any way to do this things ?

or any other methods ?

Thanks sir

Answer (score 2):

Just parse it to a string:

```
data_info.append('number', data.number.toString());
```

or

```
data_info.append('number', "" + data.number);
```

or

```
data_info.append('number', <any>data.number);
```

That will get the compiler to stop complaining

Comment: Not working it shows me error 'number type does not exist'. i want request parameter in number format.

Comment: You should change your backend then. To parse the data back to a number. You are using `URLSearchParams`. This will expand into a query `string` [?email=email&password=password&number=number]. And as you can guess, that's a string. There is no way to know what should be send as a number, because type information is not transferred. You can also try sending JSON instead of using URLSearchParams. I've added a third option though, which might work, but I doubt it